# update q defer promise before returning

Tags: angularjs

I call getBookIDs from factory and by using the result I call getBookInfo from the same factory. but in the Console.log(bookInfo) it shows me the result of previous call!
how can I update the deferred.promise value before returning??

this is my controller

```
angular.module('myApp.products',[])
    .controller('productController', function ($scope , MainFactory , $location) {
        function getBookInfo(bookIDs){
            MainFactory.getBookList(bookIDs)
                .then(function (bookInfo) {
                    console.log(bookInfo)
                })
        }

         MainFactory.getBookIDs()
             .then(function (result) {
                 $scope.bookIDList = result;
                 getBookInfo($scope.bookIDList);
             });


    });
```

and this is my factory

```
app = angular.module('myApp');

app.factory("MainFactory", ['$soap', '$http', '$q', function ($soap, $http, $q) {
    var viewFactory = {};
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    viewFactory.getBookIDs = function () {
        //var bookIDs = [];
        $http({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1/client.php?fn=getBooks',
            method: "GET"
        }).then(function success(response) {
            deferred.resolve(response.data.result);
        }, function myError(error) {
            console.log('error', error);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    viewFactory.getBookList = function (bookIDs) {
        $http({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1/client.php?fn=getBooksInfo&p1=' + bookIDs,
            method: "GET"
        }).then(function success(response) {
            deferred.resolve(response.data.result);
        }, function myError(error) {
            deferred.reject(error);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    return viewFactory;
}]);
```

Comment: You should return a new promise at each of those methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return a new promise for each of your service methods:

```
app.factory("MainFactory", ['$soap', '$http', '$q', function ($soap, $http, $q) {
    var viewFactory = {};
    viewFactory.getBookIDs = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        //var bookIDs = [];
        $http({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1/client.php?fn=getBooks',
            method: "GET"
        }).then(function success(response) {
            deferred.resolve(response.data.result);
        }, function myError(error) {
            console.log('error', error);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    viewFactory.getBookList = function (bookIDs) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1/client.php?fn=getBooksInfo&p1=' + bookIDs,
            method: "GET"
        }).then(function success(response) {
            deferred.resolve(response.data.result);
        }, function myError(error) {
            deferred.reject(error);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    return viewFactory;
}]);
```

Promises should not be reused (unless you wish to perform multiples tasks triggering the same resolve/reject... still, you should explicitly implement a promise aggregator for that, I think).

Answer (score 0):

All angular services are singletons, so i guess the reason you got this bug is `getBookIDs` and `getBookList` share the same `deferred`

try change your factory to

```
app.factory("MainFactory", ['$soap', '$http', '$q', function ($soap, $http, $q) {
    var viewFactory = {};
    viewFactory.getBookIDs = function () {
        //var bookIDs = [];
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1/client.php?fn=getBooks',
            method: "GET"
        }).then(function success(response) {
            deferred.resolve(response.data.result);
        }, function myError(error) {
            console.log('error', error);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    viewFactory.getBookList = function (bookIDs) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1/client.php?fn=getBooksInfo&p1=' + bookIDs,
            method: "GET"
        }).then(function success(response) {
            deferred.resolve(response.data.result);
        }, function myError(error) {
            deferred.reject(error);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    return viewFactory;
}]);
```